# Pollard's rho factorization turns out slower than trial division?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization, analysis-of-algorithms

Learning basic number theory, I wrote a simple program to factorise integers by trial division. The next task was to learn and implement Pollard rho algorithm (hopefully, order(s) of magnitude faster than trial division). Surprisingly, my pollard-rho program is hardly faster than the trial-division one, and just "hangs" (runs for more **hours** than I can possibly wait) factorising a repunit (31 ones):

1111111111111111111111111111111 = 2791 • 6943319 • 1996182842661949511

which trial-division manages to factor in reasonable time (18 seconds for a C program, 11 minutes for Python).

My question is, **is my implementation wrong or blatantly ineffective, or what else am I missing?**

I admit I definitely don't understand the algorithm well enough, especially the "loop detection" part or the part when the algorithm "returns an error" (xi == xj for some i!=j).

I bluntly implemented a ready algorithm from [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_rho_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) :

```
    x ← 2, y ← 2, d ← 1
    while d = 1:
        x ← g(x)
        y ← g(g(y))
        d ← gcd(|x - y|, n)
    if d = n: 
        return failure
    else:
        return d
```

Here is my Python implementation:

````
import sys

def gcd(a, b):   # assumes a >= 0
    if b < 0:
        b = -b
    if a < b:
        a, b = b, a
    if a == 0:
        return float('NaN')    # gcd(0, 0)
    while b > 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def pollard_rho(n):
    x = 2
    y = 2
    d = 1
    while (d == 1):
        x = (x * x + 1) % n
        y = (y * y + 1) % n
        y = (y * y + 1) % n
        d = gcd(n, x - y)
    if d == n:
        return float('NaN')    # signal an error
    else:
        return d

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit(f"Usage: {sys.argv[0]} <number_to_factor>")

n = int(sys.argv[1])

dividend = n
divisors = []

while dividend > 1:
    divisor = pollard_rho(dividend)
    if divisor != divisor:    # pollard_rho() returned an error
        divisors.append('?' + str(dividend) + '?')    # god knows if dividend is prime?
        break
    else:        
        divisors.append(divisor)    # may not be prime, I don't care at this stage
        dividend //= divisor

print(n, "=", ' * '.join(map(str, divisors)))
```
````

Comment: Note that Pollard-Rho can even fail ! It is only better than trial division in the average case (complexity : around the square-root of the smallest prime factor).

Comment: Python needs 11 minutes to find so small factors by trial division ? I cannot believe this !

Comment: @Peter there are lots of disclaimers with which I could start, e. g. I run this on a 10 year old PC, I am only learning Python and my implementation may be far from optimal etc. etc. But before me going this way, can you answer 2 questions:
1. How many divisors, do you think, the python program (only using trial division) tries to figure out 1996182842661949511 is prime?
2. In ordinary CPUs (I have an Intel Core 7 from 2013), division is a) slow; b) very slow; c) surprisingly slow ?